# Tetrahedron in vector space: Finding a vector connecting two points

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vector-spaces

*Edited to add: The tetrahedron is not necessarily a regular one.*

[image: Tetrahedron ABCD]

- First off, the point $M$ is the *centre of gravity* for this tetrahedron.
- I have a base $\{e_1,e_2,e_3\} = \{\vec{AB},\vec{AC},\vec{AM}\}$ and I place the point $E$, lying on the line $AD$, **three** times farther away from $A$ than from $D$ (see figure).

How could I find the vector $\vec{BE}$ using vector algebra?

*I'm new to linear algebra so sorry if this is obvious.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, we need to find $\vec {AD}$.  Following the discussion [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid#Of_triangle_and_tetrahedron), we note that
$$
\vec {AM} = 
\frac 14
\left(
\underbrace{\vec{AA}}_{\vec 0} + \vec{AB} + \vec{AC} + \vec{AD}
\right) \implies \\
\vec{AD} = 4 \vec{AM} - \vec{AB} - \vec{AC}
$$
From there, we note that
$$
\vec{AE} + \frac 13 \vec{AE}= \vec {AD} \implies\\
\vec{AE} = \frac 34 \vec{AD}
$$
Finally, we have
$$
\vec{BE} = \vec{BA} + \vec{AE} = -\vec{AB} + \vec{AE} = \frac 34\vec{AD} - \vec{AB}
$$
Putting it all together, we have
$$
\vec{BE} = 
3 \vec{AM} - \frac 74 \vec{AB} - \frac 34 \vec{AC} = \\
-\frac 74 e_1 - \frac 34 e_2 + 3e_3 
$$